# Iterators v.s. index based for loops in Qt

Tags: qt, iterator, indexing

> For that reason, iterators are rarely
>   useful in connection with QList. One
>   place where STL-style iterators do
>   make sense is as arguments to generic

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.2/qlist-iterator.html

So if I have a for loop, where the macro foreach isn't an option. Should I use iterators or indexes?

```
  for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

       Do something with list[i]

       blah blah blah

  }



  for(QList<type>::iterator i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i) {

          Do something with *i

          blah blah blah

  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Qt has it own foreach macro. I also can´t think of a reason why foreach is not an option...

The most important difference is whether you need to modify the list contents in the loop, as this may get harder to read with index API.

If you just want to do something for each of the items i have those preferences:

1. Use foreach with a (const-)reference type and let the framework do the right thing
2. Use index api ::at(int) (Quote from 4.7 docs: "QList is implemented in such a way that direct index-based access is just as fast as using iterators" & "at() can be faster than operator[]"
3. Use iterator API

But it really is just a question of style. If this is something so critical for performance that you need to worry about the minor differences you should think about redesign or writing your own specialized list.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what "blah blah blah" really does, but usually I'd choose the latter form in conjunction with `std::foreach` function, but it's only a matter of taste, I suppose.

By the way, do you mean `std::foreach` when you write macro foreach? If so, pay attention to the fact that it is not a macro.

Comment: Thanks for answering. If it's a matter of taste, it is definitely more convenient for me to use indexes in my program. I was referring to Qt's foreach which the doc says is a macro, I didn't know the STL had one too.

Answer (score 2):

I'd also consider what the performance penalty may be between the two versions.  Constantly computing list[i] is much more costly than computing ++i once.  If you really want to use index notation and not suffer too much performance loss, I suggest throwing a reference in there to hold things.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {

   ListItem &list_item = list[i];

   // do something with list_item
}
```

[I'd also use ++i instead of i++ as it is supposedly faster as a general rule.]

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example, there is no big difference.

Apart from that, it's always a good idea to learn using stl-type iterators, but they come in especially handy when you start learning the stl algorithms, like indeed `foreach`.  But don't stop there - certainly go for `transform`, `sort`, `remove_copy_if` and many more.

After all, they're part of the standard library!

Comment: Hi, thanks. I was wondering, because iterators are not really intuitive for my application and I thought that maybe in Qt is different than when you are programming with the standard library. Mostly because of that sentence I quoted.